# WordPress.org theme submission

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have approved 2 WordPress theme on ThemeForest. I know better about Themeforest theme submission guidelines. 
But it's time I am going to submit a theme on WordPress.org repository. My Question is. could I include Third-party WordPress plugin in my theme from WordPress repository?

if you know it. kindly let me know. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the official theme [submission guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/submitting-your-theme-to-wordpress-org/)

The answer is no.

> - Themes cannot include plugins.
> - Themes cannot require plugins to work.
> - Themes may recommend plugins from WordPress.org or third-party sites (link to them as free or upsell plugins, GPL licensed only).
> - Themes may use TGM Plugin Activation to recommend only plugins hosted on WordPress.org (by using 'required' => false for each
>     plugin).
> - Themes may include libraries such as option frameworks (these must pass the requirements).

[plugins](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/required/#plugins)

You can't include them. You can build a notice telling the user to install a wordpress.org plugin.

Comment: Thanks, Janw. I knew it. but I was confused. but Now I am convinced from your message

Comment: If this asnwer solved your problem be sure to mark ik as solved

Comment: Janw, could you please tell me? how I could mark it as solved?

Comment: It appears you have figured it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use the plugin according to the @janw answer  and also check the guidelines he provided you in their answer